# how to catch key event on textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

if i have focus on textbox and i press enter or Esc

how to catch this event ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript onkeyup event directly:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" onkeyup="keyPress(event)" />
```

Ore use the C# alternative:

```
Text1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "keyPress(this)");
```

Then the script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function keyPress(e)
    {
        var textBox = document.getElementById('Text1');

        var keynum;

        if (window.event) // IE
            keynum = e.keyCode;
        if (e.which) // Other browser
            keynum = e.which;

        switch (keynum)
        {
            case 13:
                //enter key
                break;
            case 27:
                //esc
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) there are some guidelines to catch the keystrokes in JavaScript, with a sample at the bottom.